# Laravel Run Route When All Are Registered

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing, laravel-artisan

Laravel has a great route manager, but I want to know how it is working

In my example, I have registered two routes.

```php
<?php

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::get('/home', function () {
    return view('home');
});
```

I think laravel will store all `$uri` and `callback`. After that when access `http://abc.domain/xyz`. Laravel will map `xyz` with `['', 'home']`. But in my example laravel will register them to `['', 'home']` only and i don'nt know where that laravel `map` run call.

Comment: what do you mean by run?

Comment: @YassineQoraiche plz see my update

Comment: It's open source. https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.7/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php

Answer (score 0):

I dont know what you really want but the `route:list` command can be used to show a list of all the registered routes for the application